# SKProductsRequest returns no products sometimes

Tags: swift

Since some days the `SKProductsResponse` contains an empty `products` array sometimes.

The `SKProductsRequest` is always successful and calls the delegate function `productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse)`.

Also older versions of the app show this behaviour, where it is sure that the `SKProductsRequest` always worked as expected.

Over 50% of all requests are affected.

Using Swift 3, iOS 10.2 (Simulator) or 10.2.1 (iPhone).

Does anyone have a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the reason was a temporary issue with Apple's servers. The problem disappeared after some hours.

As I have found some articles which state the same problem at other times, it seems that these symptoms occur at times and then disappear again.